# How to get Maxmind's Geoip database to work with Postgres + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, geoip

Anyone here running on Rails 3+, Heroku, Pgsql, and using [Maxmind's Geoip](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csv) database?

On MySql, I was able to get a simple query to work, via:

```
IpToCountry.where('ip_to_countries.ip_number_to >= INET_ATON(?)', '24.24.24.24').order('ip_number_to ASC').limit(1).first
```

However, since moving onto Pgsql, I am trying to find a way to query the db properly. So far I have:

```
remote_ip_array = '24.24.24.24'.split('.')
remote_ip_number = 16777216*remote_ip_array[0].to_i + 65536*remote_ip_array[1].to_i + 256*remote_ip_array[2].to_i + remote_ip_array[3].to_i
ip_to_country = IpToCountry.where('? >= ip_number_from AND ? <= ip_number_to', remote_ip_number, remote_ip_number).order('ip_number_to ASC').limit(1).first
```

The problem with above query, is that some IP's are not matching. For example: `37.59.16.123` and `108.166.92.235`.

I looked at [ip4r](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/ip4r/) but since I am using http://postgres.heroku.com, I may not have the option to install this. I sent the support team an email to verify.

In the meantime, any other feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't ruby contain inet_aton / inet_ntoa functions that you can use?

Comment: Yes, there is `IPAddr.new('24.24.24.24').to_i` and `IPAddr.new(3232246293, Socket::AF_INET).to_s`. However, my query `IpToCountry.where('? >= ip_number_from AND ? <= ip_number_to', remote_ip_number, remote_ip_number).order('ip_number_to ASC').limit(1).first` still reutnr nil for IP's: `37.59.16.123` and `108.166.92.235`

Comment: You could try to verify that you don't have any negative values in the DB. I know that some implementations make use of signed integers meaning that the range is between -2147483647 and 2147483647 instead of 0-4294967295

Comment: And as a side note, 37.59.16.123 doesn't return anything using the downloadable version of the DB and their own API. 108.166.92.235 returns 'US', however, I'm using an old database. They don't have 100% coverage.

Answer (score 1):

ip4r is unlikely to help with matching per se.  ip4r is mostly needed if you need GIN indexing for subnets, for example to enforce constraints that stored CIDR blocks cannot overlap.

You have two options.  The first, best one, is to use PostgreSQLs inet type and store the ipv4 addresses in type inet.  Then you'd use the standard text representation.  For example, compare:

```
select '10.59.3.1'::text > '101.3.4.1';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

with

```
select '10.59.3.1'::inet > '101.3.4.1';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

This type is included in vanilla PostgreSQL so you don't need addons.

The second option would be to create an int(inet) function as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_int(inet) RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS $$
SELECT $1 - '0.0.0.0';
$$;
```

Then

```
select to_int('10.0.0.1');
  to_int   
-----------
 167772161
(1 row)
```

This way you can do the ipv4 to int in your db.

I would recommend the inet types though. They are really helpful.  You don't need ip4r for most use cases.